# when does RSA_eay_private_decrypt called the rsa_mod_exp function?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, rsa

I summary the function call in rsa-encryption of openssl. We can found that

```
if (p!=NULL && q != NULL && dmp1 !=NULL && dmq1 != NULL && iqmp !=NULL),
```

RSA_eay_private_decrypt() and RSA_eay_private_encrypt() will call rsa_mod_exp(Is this the Chinese Reminder Theory(CRT) version?).

[image]

My questions are:

1. In publick encrypt or public decrypt, "e too small" is the reason that only call bn_mod_exp function?
2. In private_decrypt or private_encrypt, as I know, d is as big as modulur n. when does rsa_mod_exp() is called? and when bn_mod_exp() is called?

Comment: Can anyone explain/clarify this question?

Comment: I find that when dealing with public-encrypt or public-decrypt, we don't have the messages of "p,q,dmp1,dmq1,iqmp" in the public-key, so we can only call the bn_mod_exp to encrypt or decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for the branch is evident in the quoted source. It is looking for RSA_FLAG_EXT_PKEY, and looking that all "components" exist. You won't necessarily have all of the components -- you might just have the modulus and exponent of the private key to work with.

A search for "bn_mod_exp vs rsa_mod_exp" found this:

> If RSA_FLAG_EXT_PKEY is set, all private key operations go through the
>   rsa_mod_exp handler. If not, private key operations go through
>   rsa_mod_exp only if all the private key components exist (for CRT)
>   otherwise they fall back to bn_mod_exp.

-- [cf. here for the entire post](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg17545.html)

Update:

Regarding RSA_FLAG_EXT_PKEY, from rsa.h:

```
/* This flag means the private key operations will be handled by rsa_mod_exp
 * and that they do not depend on the private key components being present:
 * for example a key stored in external hardware. Without this flag bn_mod_exp
 * gets called when private key components are absent.
 */
#define RSA_FLAG_EXT_PKEY       0x20
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean, in a server, when dealing with private-decrypt, RSA_FLAG_EXP_PKEY will be always(or recommended) set for speed? As we know CRT(using two 1024 mod_exp) is faster than 2048 mod_exp.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've updated my answer to include a quote from rsa.h.